# Constant Laplacian with Dirichlet condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I start saying that it's clearly an easy problem, but I'm stupidly stuck, so be kind please.

The problem is:

$
 \mbox{Given}\ \Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n\ \mbox{bounded and }\ v \in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})\ \mbox{such that } -\Delta v=2 \mbox{ in }\Omega \mbox{ and } v=0 \mbox{ in } \partial \Omega
$

Prove that $v \in C^\infty (\Omega)$

It's clear that it's true. My idea was to use Green's representation theorem but I get stuck with the $\partial_\nu v$ term.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I wouldn’t say this problem is easy - it really depends on what you’ve learnt. Do you know that harmonic functions are smooth?

Comment: Yeah, if you mollify an harmonic function the result is smooth but you can prove (using mean value theorem) that is the original function

Comment: Ok, great. Now, can you think of an explicit function $v\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ that satisfies $-\Delta v =1$ in $\mathbb R^n$? Because then $u-2v$ is harmonic in $\Omega$, so $u-2v\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ which means that $u$ is the sum of two smooth functions

Comment: shouldn't v vanish on the boundary like u?

Comment: No because you only care about the interior regularity. If you wanted to show that $u\in C^\infty(\overline \Omega)$ then it’d be different

Comment: The only result you’re using is that harmonic functions are smooth which doesn’t require any statement about boundary conditions, so neither does this

Comment: oh true, thanks so much. I've never seen the solution to $-\Delta v = 1$ my guess would be writing $u(x)=u_1(x_1) \dots u_n(x_n)$ and solving the system of odes, is it right?

Comment: You might struggle with that guess… Try solving $-\Delta u=1$ in $\mathbb R$ i.e. $-u’’=1$ then use this to guess the general case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151043/discussion-between-jackt-and-manneredpizza).

Comment: I've answered on the chat